# Converting coordinates to congressional districts using DSTK's API in R

Tags: r, api, geocoding

First time asker, though frequent lurker. I've had a lot of questions answered through reading other Q+As on Stack Overflow, so this being the one I haven't seen an answer to yet, I figured I'd throw it out there.

I have a large number of Lat/Long values associated with unique IDs that I need to get the congressional districts for (a large number being roughly 90K...). I obtained these through ggmap, calling the Data Science Toolkit to return Geos. The Data Science Toolkit also has an API to return political information using coordinates, but I have no idea how to write code in R to query it and return only the value I need (eg. "Eighth district, CA") and add it to the dataframe as a column.

I've posted a very small sample of my data so you can see how it's structured, and [this is the home of the API](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#coordinates2politics). I apologize if anything here is rudimentary, I'm very new to this. Any assistance that can be provided would be sincerely appreciated!

[image]

SOLVED using the solution recommended by hrbrmstr:

```
#Assumes working from a CSV with two columns for Lat/Long and one with an ID
# Load the required packages. 
require(rgdal)
require(sp)
require(maps)
require(tigris)

#Uses the tigris package to pull in the congressional districts
districts <- congressional_districts(cb = TRUE, resolution = '20m')

#Upload data to a dataframe
geos<-read.csv("Codes.csv")

#converts the Latitude and Lontitude columns into a Geospatial Data Frame
coordinates(geos) <- c("longitude", "latitude")

#Sets Proj4Strings of geos to that of districts
proj4string(geos)<-proj4string(districts)

#determines which districts contain geos
inside.district <- !is.na(over(geos, as(districts, "SpatialPolygons")))
#Checks the fraction of geos inside a district
mean(inside.district)

#Takes the values for District and adds them to your geos data
geos$District <- over(geos,districts)$CD114FP
#Takes the values for State and adds them to your geos data
geos$State <- over(geos,districts)$STATEFP

#Exports the geos data to a CSV
write.csv(geos, "Districts.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: take a look at the `tigris` package. You'll be able to get a shapefile of the districts then you can convert your lat/lon pairs to SpatialPoints and run `over` on them to get the districts (and more) info. also, a picture is not data. Either a `dput` or real CSV output would be much better. Also see the [reprex pkg](https://github.com/jennybc/reprex).

Comment: Thank you! I apologize for the picture, I just wanted to show the set visually to give an idea. I will input csv data in future. I will check out the tigris package and see how it works!

Comment: Wanted to add that if you are starting with addresses instead of lat/lon coordinates, you'll need to geocode them first. If you have a lot of addresses to process, you can setup your own geocoder using PostGIS following these instructions - https://github.com/postgis/postgis/tree/svn-trunk/extras/tiger_geocoder. There are also some services that will take an address and give back the congressional district for you like LatLon.io (https://latlon.io)

Comment: For historical congressional districts, one can download the historical shapefile from http://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/ and follow the same procedure. ```congressional_districts``` package only goes back to 2011.